# How to brush/modify the values of a Series between two different values according to rules, not changing the marks?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
nan = np.NaN
data = [['a1',0,'Bottom_Class'],
        ['a1',0,nan],
        ['a1',1,nan],
        ['a1',1,nan],
        ['a1',1,nan],
        ['a1',1,'Top_Class'],
        ['a1',0,'Bottom_Class'],
        ['a1',0,'Top_Class'],
        ['a2',1,nan],
        ['a2',1,nan],
        ['a2',1,'Bottom_Class'],
        ['a2',0,nan],
        ['a2',0,'Bottom_Class'],
        ['a1',0,'Top_Class'],
        ['a2',1,nan],
        ['a1',1,'Top_Class'],
        ['a2',1,nan],
        ['a2',1,nan],
        ['a2',1,nan],
        ['a2',0,'Bottom_Class']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Id','State','Class'])
print(df)
    Id  State         Class
0   a1      0  Bottom_Class
1   a1      0           NaN
2   a1      1           NaN
3   a1      1           NaN
4   a1      1           NaN
5   a1      1     Top_Class
6   a1      0  Bottom_Class
7   a1      0     Top_Class
8   a2      1           NaN
9   a2      1           NaN
10  a2      1  Bottom_Class
11  a2      0           NaN
12  a2      0  Bottom_Class
13  a1      0     Top_Class
14  a2      1           NaN
15  a1      1     Top_Class
16  a2      1           NaN
17  a2      1           NaN
18  a2      1           NaN
19  a2      0  Bottom_Class
```

So this is a dataframe of some stock market prices, but I modify it sothat easier to understand.

Just to focus on df.Class:

My thought is to set: a **Bottom_Class** as a starting point, and **Top_Class** as the end point. And Vice Versas.

And value after(not including itself) Top_Class will be set to **0**, until it meets Bottom_Class

and
value after(not including itself) Bottom_Class will be set to **1**,  until it meets Top_Class.

**I want the Series to be modified like this:**

```
Class
Bottom_Class
1
1
1
1
Top_Class
Bottom_Class
Top_Class
0
0
Bottom_Class
1
Bottom_Class
Top_Class
0
Top_Class
0
0
0
Bottom_Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `np.where` and use `fillna` to fill only `NaN` values

```
df.Class.fillna(pd.Series(np.where(df.Class.ffill() == 'Bottom_Class',1,0)))

# Output:

0     Bottom_Class
1                1
2                1
3                1
4                1
5        Top_Class
6     Bottom_Class
7        Top_Class
8                0
9                0
10    Bottom_Class
11               1
12    Bottom_Class
13       Top_Class
14               0
15       Top_Class
16               0
17               0
18               0
19    Bottom_Class
```

Comment: `df.Class.fillna(df.Class.ffill().eq('Bottom_Class').astype(int))`